# C# Generic constructor parameter from inherited class

Tags: c#

I'm searching for a solution that I have a generic constructor parameter where the T is the type of the derived class:

```cs
public abstract BaseClass{
   // The generic T in Position should be the Type of the inherited class
   public BaseClass(Position<T> position){
        Position = position;
   }
}


public class A : BaseClass{
    public A(Position<A> position): base(position){}
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You cannot have a generic ctor without your class being generic. Having said this all you need is `public abstract BaseClass<T>`, and then `A: BaseClass<A>`.

Comment: But the generic cannot be self-refering? ```public abstract class BaseClass<T> where T : BaseClass```

Comment: @SNO yes it can: `where T : BaseClass<T>`. But if you have multiple childclasses (eg. `A` and `B`), you cannot stop something like `public class B : BaseClass<A>`

Comment: This is called Curiously Recurring Template Pattern https://blog.stephencleary.com/2022/09/modern-csharp-techniques-1-curiously-recurring-generic-pattern.html many articles on it. Unfortunately we don't have `where T : this` so you have to settle for `where T : BaseClass<T>`. You can prevent the case of @JeanotZubler by making validation in a constructor `BaseClass() { if (this is not T) throw new Exception("Invalid type"); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a generic ctor without your class being generic. Having said this all you need is `public abstract BaseClass<T>`, and then `A: BaseClass<A>`.

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T>
{
    // The generic T in Position should be the Type of the inherited class    
    public BaseClass(Position<T> position)
    {
        Position = position;    
    } 
}
public class A : BaseClass<A>
{
    public A(Position<A> position): base(position){} 
}
```

Comment: Problem here is, you can do something like `public class B : BaseClass<A>`, or even `public class B : BaseClass<string>`. Even with an added restriction on the type parameter `where T : BaseClass<T>` this cannot totally be prevented

Comment: And I guess this cannot be restricted by ```where T : BaseClass```

Comment: @SNO if it's sufficient for you, you can check the type in the constructor at least

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this restriction is sufficient for you. But you can check the type in the constructor at least.
Something like this

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T> where T : BaseClass<T>
{
    // The generic T in Position should be the Type of the inherited class    
    public BaseClass(Position<T> position)
    {
        if (this is not T)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Expected {typeof(T).Name}, but got {GetType().Name}.");
        }

        Position = position;
    }

    public Position<T> Position { get; }
}

public class A : BaseClass<A>
{
    public A(Position<A> position) : base(position) { }
}
```